# If $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{p}]$ with $p$ an odd prime and $I=(2,1+\sqrt{p})$, then $I^2=(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to show that if $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{p}]$ with $p$ an odd prime such that $p \equiv 3 \hspace{1mm} (\operatorname{mod} 4)$ and $I$ is the ideal generated by $2$ and $1+\sqrt(p)$ then $I^2$ is the ideal generated by $2$

I know that
$$I^2=(4,2+2\sqrt{p},1+p+2\sqrt{p})$$
and that $4,2+2\sqrt{p},1+p+2\sqrt{p} \in (2)$, so I just need to prove that $2 \in I^2$ but I cannot prove it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't drop an assumption that $ p \equiv 3 \pmod{4} $ somewhere?

Comment: @EgeErdil Yes, sorry I'll edit it.

Comment: Hint: what do you get if you subtract the second generator of $I^2$ there from the third?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3102984/242) in the linked duipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ p \equiv 3 \pmod{4} $, then $ (4, 2 + 2 \sqrt{p}, 1 + p + 2 \sqrt{p}) = (4, 2 + 2 \sqrt{p}, p - 1) $ and since $ \gcd(p-1, 4) = 2 $ this is equal to $ (2, 2 + 2 \sqrt{p}) = (2) $.